# Copying Context.Request to HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to forward a request coming to an Aspnet handler (ashx) to another handler **on another server**.
Is there a clean way to copy

```
Context.Request
```

To

```
HttpWebRequest
```

Or should I copy this manually (Headers and content)?

Comment: You can create instance of the http handler class and call the process request method ? If you want to pass additional parameters too then you can use the HttpContext.Current.Items collection.

Comment: You can use `Server.Transfer()`. This will preserve the current HttpContext. Is there a special reason to copy the Context.Request to HttpWebRequest? I think it is not necessary for what you need.

Comment: @Akhil the other handler is on another server

Comment: @OguzOzgul actually this won't work since the other endpoint is another server

Comment: But you did not mention that in your question, did you :)

Comment: @OguzOzgul, I will add it to the question, no worries.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing http handler class and create an instance of it

```
MyHttpHandler obj=new MyHttpHandler();
obj.ProcessRequest(HttpContext);
```

If you want to pass any additional parameters use HttpContext.Current.Items collection.

Comment: But did you know that the handler was on another server :)

Comment: Ah, I did not see that :(